# Java Compile error : cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I wrote a Java program but I'm getting an error:

```
ArrayMain.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
            ar[c]=input.nextInt;
                       ^
  symbol:   variable nextInt
  location: variable input of type Scanner
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArrayMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size:");
        int c=input.nextInt();
        int[] ar=new int[c];
        System.out.println("Enter Element");
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            ar[c]=input.nextInt;
        }

        array(ar,c);
    }
    public static void array(int[] ar,int c);
    {
        System.out.println("Elements in reverse order are");
        for(int i=c;i>0;i--);
        {
            System.out.println(ar[c-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: I recommend you to watch java tutorial and view java documentation to be more familiar with syntax of java:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPvGqX-TXP0

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 ar[c]=input.nextInt();
```

and also make sure the method definition is correct

```
public static void array(int[] ar,int c) {   //notice the removal of semicolon
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ar[c] = input.nextInt;
```

It's wrong and the correct code is:

```
ar[c] = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put the index `i` instead of `c` in `ar[c]` to loop over each input element

```
System.out.println("Enter Element");
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        ar[i]=input.nextInt();  //not input.nextInt
    }
```

also method `array(int[] ar,int c)` have problems it should be:

```
public static void array(int[] ar,int c) // method decleration shouldn't end with `;`
{
    System.out.println("Elements in reverse order are");
    // for loop mustn't end with ';' for(int i=c;i>0;i--);
    for(int i=c-1;i>=0;i--)  // start at last element index to the first element which index is i=0
    {
        System.out.println(ar[i]);   // loop over each element in reverse order
    }
}
```